# WiFi in Ubuntu 14, but no WiFi in 16 & 17?

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04, 14.10

On three different desktop computers all sitting in the same room, if 14 is loaded Wifi works fine. 
If I clean install 16 or 17.04 wifi stops working. 
I have two different usb adapters I tried in each machine and they work in 14 but not 16 or 17. The adapter that’s built into the motherboard (of one machine) Has the same behavior.

Very strange.

I thought the first computer (a 10D ThinkStation) fried the adapters because they just stopped working. Booting to 14 again, allowed all three adapters to work fine again. 
Under 17 one USB adapter shows the available (SSIDs) I can connect to but it never connects, only tries when I click on one. The other USB adapter under 17 does not show anything is avalable to connect to and thus does not connect - it does allow wifi to be enabled though. 
Under 14 all the wifi adapters work fine and consistently. 
The only change is the version of Ubuntu.

Is there something about 16 or 17 I should know to allow me to get wifi going?

I did a lot of searching before asking this question but did not find the answer. 
In the past these adapters worked out of the box easy with no proprietary drivers needed.

SOLUTIONS: 
On the first computer the ThinkStation D10 I reset the bios to factory defaults and that fixed the wifi problem once I clean installed 16.04 from cd. 
It also allowed me to install without using a special boot command acpi=off. I get the impression the issue might have involved the power to usb rather than the wifi adapters.

On the second computer, a custom built quad core, I reset the bios to factory defaults and that fixed the wifi problem once I clean installed 16.04 from cd. Clean installing from 17.04 after resetting the bios did not allow the wifi to work. 
Of note, reseting the bios did not fix the problem unless I did a clean install after that.

Same with computer three although I had to turn off fast boot.

Responding to those who have offered help: (thank you)

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill
```

Soft and hard blocked produced no for answers.

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf - did not list them, that I could tell. Clarity on what to look for might help.

The adapters show up in Ubuntu (in the main desktop GUI) as SSIDs that I can connect to and can be clicked on - they just never actually connect once clicked on.

“If the adapters require unsigned drivers you should disable Secure Boot in newer releases. – MichaelBay”

How would I know if they take unsigned drivers? 
Is disabling secure boot done within the bios? If so, my system does not have that option - likely to old.

Additionally, are there any usb 3 or better AC or better adapters recommendations for use in Ubuntu?

Thank you all for your help - I have been using Ubuntu since Hardy or so. 
I like to try to do things the Ubuntu way rather than fight it. I like the open source movement and the many philosophies and philosophers. I. E. This is not supposed to be Windows or such. Loving it.

Comment: Maybe these devices are blacklisted on newer versions. Please edit your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command. Inspect `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` to see if they are in this file.

Comment: If the adapters require unsigned drivers you should disable Secure Boot in newer releases.